# Add/Update error in Php ajax crud operation?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have used ajax for a crud operation in php. when i run the program it works fine, i "edit" my data and it works fine but when i click "add" after editing, the details i add just upgrading the last data i edit. what seems to be the problem?

```
   <script>  
   $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       $('#insert').val("Insert");  
       $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#name').val(data.name);  
                 $('#address').val(data.address);  
                 $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                 $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                 $('#age').val(data.age);  
                 $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                 $('#insert').val("Update");  
                 $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
            }  
       });  
  });  
  $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
       event.preventDefault();  
       if($('#name').val() == "")  
       {  
            alert("Name is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#address').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Address is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Designation is required");  
       }  
       else if($('#age').val() == '')  
       {  
            alert("Age is required");  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"insert.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                 beforeSend:function(){  
                      $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                 },  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                      $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                      $('#employee_table').html(data);  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
       var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       if(employee_id != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"select.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                 success:function(data){  
                      $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                      $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                 }  
            });  
       }            
      });  
      });  
     </script>
```

And the Php server side code is given below:

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
 if(!empty($_POST))  
 {  
  $output = '';  
  $message = '';  
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"]);  
  $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["address"]);  
  $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["gender"]);  
  $designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["designation"]);  
  $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["age"]);  
  if($_POST["employee_id"] != '')  
  {  
       $query = "  
       UPDATE tbl_employee   
       SET name='$name',   
       address='$address',   
       gender='$gender',   
       designation = '$designation',   
       age = '$age'   
       WHERE id='".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";  
       $message = 'Data Updated';  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $query = "  
       INSERT INTO tbl_employee(name, address, gender, designation, age)  
       VALUES('$name', '$address', '$gender', '$designation', '$age');  
       ";  
       $message = 'Data Inserted';  
  }  
  if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
  {  
       $output .= '<label class="text-success">' . $message . '</label>';  
       $select_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id DESC";  
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);  
       $output .= '  
            <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <tr>  
                      <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                      <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                      <th width="15%">View</th>  
                 </tr>  
       ';  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= '  
                 <tr>  
                      <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>  
                      <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" 
  id="'.$row["id"] .'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                      <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" 
  id="' . $row["id"] . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                 </tr>  
            ';  
       }  
       $output .= '</table>';  
  }  
  echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Full source code can be viewed at http://www.webslesson.info/2016/10/php-ajax-update-mysql-data-through-bootstrap-modal.html

And demo can be viewed at http://www.itidabhoi.org/demo/bootstrap-crud-php/

The problem still appears in demo as well.

Comment: need some solution..please somebody help...

Comment: I don't think such code should be published as a tutorial or web lesson. Anyway, the issue is that you don't clear the value of #employee_id before submitting the insert form after it has previously been set by the edit_data on click handler.

Comment: It also looks like you are returning somethings as HTML `$('#employee_table').html(data)` and some as JSON, `$('#address').val(data.address);` but I don't see any JSON being returned by the PHP code.  Maybe it's not in the post.  But it's confusing to do both.

Comment: Artistic Phoenix what could be the solution??

Comment: @RajKumar the solution to what Phoenix is talking about is to use a consistent data format - stick to either returning JSON or HTML consistently from all your server methods. le_m gave you the solution to your stated question.

Comment: Also, `WHERE id='".$_POST["employee_id"]."'";` seems to allow SQL injections.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix problem solved...thanks for your precious suggestion cheers  ....

Comment: What was wrong? It may be worth posting an answer yourself in case someone sees this later.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  
The wrong i did was after clicking edit button I did not reset the previously set employee_id. I reset the id like this
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#add').click(function(){  
       $('#insert').val("Insert");  
       $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
        $('#employee_id').val('');

Comment: @RajKumar if you add that as an answer instead of a comment you can accept your own answer, and also people can upvote it if they want to, which gains you reputation points. Plus it's clearer for future readers, who may have a similar problem, what the definite solution was.

Comment: Regarding le_m's last comment, your code is certainly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Thank you guys ...cheers